# Ruby 1.8 and UTF-8 string case statement compare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, ruby-1.8

I have a Rake task (in lib/tasks directory) that I run with cron on my shared web hosting. The problem is that I want to compare a UTF-8 string using case statment but my source code is not UTF-8 encoded. If I save source code as UTF-8 there is error when I try to start it :(

What I have to do?

May be read this strings from external UTF-8 txt file?

P.S. I'm using Ruby 1.8

P.S. I mean compare this way:

```
result = case utf8string
   when 'АБВ': 1
   when 'ГДИ': 2
   when 'ЙКЛ': 3
   when 'МНО': 4
   else 5
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you need to change your text editor as BOM is *not* needed for UTF-8. UTF-8 is not byte-order dependent. See [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte-order_mark) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I found that my problem was not in case statment

The problem was that when I save my source code in UTF-8 format, my text editor add 3 bytes (BOM) at the beginning to indicate that encoding is UTF-8.

> **Q: What is a BOM?**
>
> **A:** A byte order mark (BOM) consists of the character code
> U+FEFF at the beginning of a data stream, where it can be used as a
> signature defining the byte order and encoding form, primarily of unmarked
> plaintext files. Under some higher level protocols, use of a BOM may be
> mandatory (or prohibited) in the Unicode data stream defined in that protocol.

[UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM)

The error that I get was:

```
1: Invalid char `\357' in expression
1: Invalid char `\273' in expression
1: Invalid char `\277' in expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mb_chars` method from Rails' [ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html) framework:

```
result = case utf8string.mb_chars
   when 'АБВ': 1
   when 'ГДИ': 2
   when 'ЙКЛ': 3
   when 'МНО': 4
   else 5
end
```