# Anyone knows what's going on with "weird" characters at the beginning of a string?

Tags: ruby

I've just run into a strange issue when trying to detect a certain string among an array of them. Anyone knows what's going on here?

```
(rdb:1) p magic_string
"﻿Time Period"
(rdb:1) p magic_string.class
String
(rdb:1) p magic_string == "Time Period"
false
(rdb:1) p "Time Period".length
11
(rdb:1) p magic_string.length
14
(rdb:1) p magic_string[0].chr
"\357"
(rdb:1) p magic_string[1].chr
"\273"
(rdb:1) p magic_string[2].chr
"\277"
(rdb:1) p magic_string[3].chr
"T"
```

Answer (score 7):

Your string contains 3 bytes (BOM) at the beginning to indicate that encoding is UTF-8.

> **Q: What is a BOM?**
>
> **A:** A byte order mark (BOM) consists of the character code U+FEFF at
>   the beginning of a data stream, where it can be used as a signature
>   defining the byte order and encoding form, primarily of unmarked
>   plaintext files. Under some higher level protocols, use of a BOM may
>   be mandatory (or prohibited) in the Unicode data stream defined in
>   that protocol.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/355422/3035830)

Answer (score 6):

This might help you to understand what's happening:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.3"
magic_string = "Time Period"
magic_string[0].chr # => "\uFEFF"
```

The same output is true with Ruby v2.2.2.

Older versions of Ruby didn't default to UTF-8 and treated strings as an array of bytes. The `encoding` line is important to tell it what the script's strings' encoding is.

Ruby now correctly treats Strings as arrays of characters not bytes, which is why it reports the first *character* as `"\uFEFF"`, a two-byte character.

`"\uFEFF"` and `"\uFFFE"` are [BOM markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) showing which "endian" the characters are. [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is tied to the CPU's idea of what a most significant and least significant byte is in a word (two bytes typically). This is also tied to [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), both of which are something you need to understand, at least in a rudimentary way as we don't deal with only ASCII any more, and languages don't consist of only the Latin character set.

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is an multibyte character set that incorporates a huge number of characters from multiple languages. You can also run into UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE or longer; HTML and documents on the internet can be encoded in varying lengths of characters depending on the originating hardware and not being aware of those can drive you nuts and you'll go down the wrong paths trying to read their content. It's important to read the IO class documentation for "[IO Encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Encoding)" to know the right way to deal with these types of files.